# Scala: Wait while List is beeing filled

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous

assume having a List where results of jobs that are computed distributed are stored.

Now I have a main thread that is waiting for all jobs finished.

I know the size of the List needs to have until all jobs are finished.
What is the most elegant way in scala let the main thread (while(true) loop) sleep and getting it awake when the jobs are finished?

thanks for your answers

**EDIT:** ok after trying the concept from @Stefan-Kunze without success (guess I didnt got the point...) I give an example with some code:

The first node:

```
class PingPlugin extends SmasPlugin
{
  val messages = new ListBuffer[BaseMessage]()

  val sum = 5

  def onStop = true

  def onStart =
  {
    log.info("Ping Plugin created!")

    true
  }

  def handleInit(msg: Init)
  {
    log.info("Init received")

    for( a <- 1 to sum)
    {
      msg.pingTarget ! Ping() // Ping extends BaseMessage
    }

    // block here until all messages are received
    // wait for messages.length == sum

    log.info("handleInit - messages received: %d/%d ".format(messages.length, sum))


  }

  /**
   * This method handles incoming Pong messages
   * @param msg Pong extends BaseMessage
   */
  def handlePong(msg: Pong)
  {
    log.info("Pong received from: " + msg.sender)
    messages += msg

    log.info("handlePong - messages received: %d/%d ".format(messages.length, sum))
  }
}
```

a second node:

```
class PongPlugin extends SmasPlugin
{
  def onStop = true

  def onStart =
  {
    log.info("Pong Plugin created!")
    true
  }

  /**
   * This method receives Ping messages and send a Pong message back after a random time
   * @param msg Ping extends BaseMessage
   */
  def handlePing(msg: Ping)
  {
    log.info("Ping received from: " + msg.sender)
    val sleep: Int = math.round(5000 * Random.nextFloat())
    log.info("sleep: " + sleep)

    Thread.sleep(sleep)
    msg.sender ! Pong()
  }
}
```

I guess the solution is possible with futures...

Comment: your use case is unclear to me: typically you consume elements from a queue.

Comment: well thanks for the remark. A synchronized queue is neither necessary nor appropriate for this case. Therefore I have to agree with you. The results better be inserted via a method with a this.synchronized{} block. I edited the question.
The use-case is a little distributed planet simulation

Comment: May be you can store all result as `Future`. Then use ```Await.result(Future.sequence(futures), Duration(10 minutes))``` to gather all results.

Comment: The question is whether you really need to block here at all with an Await. Blocking should always be the last choice. Instead you should stay with futures until you absolutely must resolve them. A good place to start is http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html. If you're using Akka, you should also look at the ask pattern, which is the Actor implementation of futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to test the code here, since I don't have the rest of this system, but I'll try. I'm assuming that somewhere underneath all of this is Akka.

First, blocking like this suggests a real design problem. In an actor system, you should send your messages and move on. Your log command should be in `handlePong` when the correct number of pings have returned. Blocking init hangs the entire actor. You really should never do that.

But, ok, what if you absolutely have to do that? Then a good tool here would be the [ask pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/futures.html). Something like this (I can't check that this compiles without more of your code):

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

...
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

var pendingPongs = List.empty[Future[Pong]]

for( a <- 1 to sum)
{
  // Ask each target for Ping. Append the returned Future to pendingPongs
  pendingPongs += msg.pingTarget ? Ping() // Ping extends BaseMessage      
}

// pendingPongs is a list of futures. We want a future of a list.
// sequence() does that for us. We then block using Await until the future completes.

val pongs = Await.result(Future.sequence(pendingPongs), 5 seconds)

log.info(s"handlePong - messages received: ${pongs.length}/$sum")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You got a good point and I had really to rethink about the blocking issue. And I aggree that your suggestion to check the received message count in `handlePong` is the better solution.
Btw: You are right I use Akka but encapsulated in an agent middleware. So the example wont compile with the rest of my code. But it gives a good introduction to the Futures concept.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Picking up @jilen 's approach: (this code is assuming your results are of a type result)

```
//just like lists futures can be yielded
val tasks: Seq[Future[Result]] = for (i <- 1 to results.size) yield future {
                                                   //results.size is the number of                   //results you are expecting
  println("Executing task " + i)
  Thread.sleep(i * 1000L)
  val result = ??? //your code goes here
  result
}


//merge all future results into a future of a sequence of results
val aggregated: Future[Seq[Result]] = Future.sequence(tasks)


//awaits for your results to be computed
val squares: Seq[Int] = Await.result(aggregated, Duration.Inf)
println("Squares: " + squares)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I guess I didn't fully understand the Futures concept yet. Instead I gave an example what I want to achieve in the initial post.

Comment: Upvoted both answeres. Thanks for your suggestions :)